# register virtual taphold event for jQuery mobile Flip toggle switch

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery

I can't figure out how to register the `taphold` event for a [Flip toggle switch](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/switch/). I tried as described [here](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/switch/events.html) with the following code.

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    Sex 
    <select name="sex" id="id" data-role="slider">
        <option value="off">Male</option>
        <option value="on">Female</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

```
$('#id').live('taphold', function(){     
    console.log("taphold");
});
```

And, because the actual `<select>` tag is hidden, and the switch is rendered by following html

```
<div role="application" class="ui-slider ui-slider-switch ui-btn-down-c ui-btn-corner-all ui-focus">
    <span class="ui-slider-label ui-slider-label-a ui-btn-active ui-btn-corner-all" role="img" style="width: 100%">Female</span>
    <span class="ui-slider-label ui-slider-label-b ui-btn-down-c ui-btn-corner-all" role="img" style="width: 0%">Male</span>
    <div class="ui-slider-inneroffset">
        <a href="#" class="ui-slider-handle ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-slider-handle-snapping ui-focus ui-btn-up-c" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="c" role="slider" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="1" aria-valuenow="on" aria-valuetext="Female" title="Female" aria-labelledby="eforms_patient_sex-label" style="left: 100%">
            <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
                <span class="ui-btn-text"/>
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which is a sibling of aboves `<select>` tag I also tried this

```
$('#id').parent().find('[role="application"]').live('taphold', function(){
    console.log("taphold");
});
```

But nether did work. So...
**How to register the virtual taphold event for jQuery mobile Flip toggle switch?**

//edit

I added a `onclick` function to the `<div>` tag, via opera dragonfly, and it worked. So It seams that registering the event to the `<div>` is the right approach. But it does not work, with the code above.

Answer (score 0):

The event is called **taphold** not tabhold.

Comment: thats embarrassing, but after changing to `taphold` I still wasn't able to register the event.